# What is an Internet-Facing Active Directory site?

Tags: active-directory

I was looking at installing Exchange 2010 on the Internet and one thing in my research that came up was, you must have an Internet-Facing Active Directory site.

What does that mean?  All I have is an Intranet, one forest, one domain.  None of it is on the Internet.  I don't know what I'd have to do to put AD on the Internet.

Comment: I'd be very nervous about exposing my AD servers to the public internet.

Comment: Is there any reason you're desperate to use Exchange 2010? It sounds to me like you're a bit out of your depth, and might do better with a hosted exchange solution.

Comment: Yes.  it must be 2010.  And putting the AD on Internet Facing is a requirement by MS, not me.  No hosting.

Comment: You've completely missed my point.  Why must you be the one to set up exchange, why not pay a company to manage it for you?

Comment: What does "installing Exchange 2010 on the Internet" actually mean? What is the problem you're trying to solve here? Are you looking to be a hosted email provider? Are you trying to let employees use email from home via OWA or whatever?

Comment: You accidentally the whole internet.

Comment: wow.  downvotes because i posted something you didn't think I should be doing...sad.

Comment: @johnny - The downvotes are because you clearly don't understand what you're asking. This is a site for professionals, we assume you know the basic concepts behind what you're asking.

Comment: @MarkM how elitist of you.  How dare I ask a "pro" question.  Ridiculous.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know where you got this information from, but either the website you got it from is misinformed, or you misunderstand (more likely).

You **do not** have to have your Active Directory servers directly connected to the internet (don't *EVER* do that by the way). What it means is that you must have an Active Directory site that has internet connectivity, typically through a router and preferably through a firewall too.

The Exchange server does need to be directly exposed to the internet (Edge Transport or Hub Transport, that's your design choice) and this is typically done by NAT'ing ports (namely 25 for SMTP and 443 for OWA) on the router to the Exchange Server. The Exchange server also requires connectivity to Active Directory to function, but Active Directory doesn't need to be directly exposed to the internet to achieve this.

Comment: I got it here:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh273153.aspx

Comment: Reading that, then yes, all it means is a site as defined in Active Directory that has internet connectivity. Internet-facing is just easier to say I guess :-)

Comment: Does that mean the first statement above is inaccurate?